# How to give permissions only to PHP to read a config directory outside the web root?

Tags: php, apache, configuration, file-permissions

I am trying to hide my db conf connection file outside the web root directory of my web server. I want to put it outside and keep the permissions as restrective as possible, in order to permit only the web administrator and the PHP interpreter to read it.

The file has this permissions:

-rw-------  1 serveradmin serveradmin  150 mar 12 01:12 db-conf.php

But when a php script inside the web root calls it using require_once '/path/outside/webroot/to/db-conf.php'; I get the php permission denied error.

**Warning: require_once(/path/outside/webroot/to/db-conf.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/php-script.php on line x

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/php-script.php on line x**

How can I resolve?

Comment: What are other possible users against whom you are protecting this file?

Comment: your question title contradicts with question body which says "PHP **and** webadmin". And both contradicts with code which says "webadmin **only**". Can't you make your mind at last?

Comment: I have resolved, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running PHP through a webserver, i.e. apache, then PHP is running as the apache user, and whatever PHP can read, apache can read, so you have to give apache read permissions to this file.  if its outside the website directory, then people won't be able to get to it through apache, but PHP will be able to find it.

Comment: So I have to give the permissions to PHP or Apache? How can I do it? using chmod?

Comment: Yes, to apache user, check what user your apache is running under, this will be in httpd.conf (possible envvars)  and then `chown -R user:group /path/to/directory`

Comment: Is it this?

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon 
------------

Guess it is daemon, cause even if I type 'top' from shell I get that the user 'daemon' is running the apache 'httpd' process.